# Vertex Paint no longer adds color

Tags: vertex-paint

I modeled my object just fine, then went into the Texture Paint tab, and, using Vertex Paint, I was able to paint my object looking kind of how I wanted. However, I did something which is now preventing me from adding any new color or changing any existing color. Whenever I try to paint, nothing happens. I have a color selected in the Color Palette, and I am using the Draw brush, with a blending mode of Mix, with a Strength of 1.000.

After playing around, I discovered that I can switch the blending mode to Vivid Light, Linear Light, or Pin Light, and it will draw on my object. However, regardless of what color I have selected, it will only draw black. If I start a new file, and go into Vertex Paint, I can color on the default cube just fine, but, when I reload my saved object, painting stops working again.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Check the brush type is "Draw" and the Blend is "Mix"

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Jan. I am trying it with a brush type of Draw, and a blending mode is Mix, but it doesn't color the object.

Comment: can you please upload the file here and share it? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I gave up and switched to using a texture instead because that painting still works. But thank you so much for wanting to help!

Comment: All those options can be sometimes confusing, I recommend to read the manual, it is really well made and maybe you will find the answer there :) https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/
Good luck (and patience) and happy Blending! :)